# Can hidden characters change the name of output files in fortran?

Tags: fortran, notepad++

I'm using a subroutine to output an array gathered from a previous function. After running my program and only calling the subroutine once, my intended file name, testf.txt, is given as "testf.txtÑ @." Thinking it was a hidden character generated by a portion I borrowed from a friend, I retyped the whole section but nothing changed. When I do multiple calls, the names of the the files add onto one another. Intended, "testf.txt" "testg.txt" "testh.txt", given, "testf.txttestg" "testg.txttesth" and "testh.txt". The content is fine, the name being the only issue. Would that be caused by hidden characters in the code, or a logic error in how the subroutine hold information?

Thanks,

Thomas

Main Program

```
  program Main
     implicit none

     !DATA DICTIONARY
     character :: selection                   ! Method of summation
                                              ! L = left Riemann sum
                                              ! R = right Riemann sum 
                                              ! M = Midpoint rule
                                              ! T = Trapezoidal rule sum
                                              ! S = Simpson's rule            
     integer :: n                             ! Number of subintervals the integral is to
                                              !  be divided into
     integer :: func                          ! The function to be integrated
                                              !  f = (28.0/5) + 2*sin(4*x) - (1/x)
                                              !  g = ln(4x) + (19x)^3 - 43
                                              !  h = 1/(sqrt(2.0*PI))*exp(-(x**2)/2.0)  
     character(20) :: filename

     real, external :: f
     real, external :: g
     real, external :: h
     real, dimension(1000) :: area


     !Declare functions used
     real :: Quad

     write(*,*) "Written in the form ",
 +              "Quad(func, n, left, right, selection):"
     write(*,*) " "

     !Test Drivers

     write(*, *) Quad(f, 10, 0.2, 3.2, 'T', area)
     call Out(10, area, 'testf.txt')
     write(*, *) Quad(g, 10, 5.0, 10.0, 'L', area) 
     call Out(10, area, 'testg.txt') 
     write(*, *) Quad(h, 25, 1.0, 10.0, 'L', area)
     call Out(10, area, 'testh.txt') 


  end program Main
```

Actual Out subroutine

```
  subroutine Out(n, area, filename) 
  !PRE: n > 0
  !     area is the initialized array area(1...n)
  !     filename is initialized
     implicit none 

     integer, intent(in) :: n 
     real, dimension(n), intent(in) :: area 
     character(20), intent(in) :: filename

     integer :: i

     open(unit=1, file=filename, form='formatted', !Writes area(1...n) to a file
 +      action='write', status='replace')

     do i = 1, n, 1
        write(1,*) area(i)
     end do

     close(unit=1)
  end subroutine Out
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add an exerpt of the code. At least the line that calls `OPEN` and relevant variable declarations.

Comment: you should use either `character*(*)` or `character(len=*)` for the dummy argument `filename` in the subroutine. Maybe someone will put an answer with some more explanation, but really, this stuff is easy to find on the internet if you search a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of error is normally an indication of one or more of:

1. Array overruns - i.e. if your data is in an array of size 10 followed by your filen ame in memory and you write to array element 11 it will corrupt the file name.
2. Array under run - similar to the above but at the start of the array
3. Parameter corruption - if the text for the file name is passed as a read write parameter then it can be overwritten in the code.

You can often sort out this sort of issue by a) turn on all compiler error checking and fix all the warnings and/or b running the code through a lint equivalent such as [ftnchek](http://www.dsm.fordham.edu/~ftnchek/) and fixing the issues it finds.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try each of those in turn.

Comment: Given this error thrice:", line 284: The length of scalar character actual argument of procedure 'Out' shall be greater than or equal to the length of the dummy argument 'filename'. The previous definition is in 'line 227'." I changed my test driver to call the variable "filename", as opposed to inputting the text value. [filename = 'file' ... call Out(10, area, filename) instead of call Out(10, area, 'file') Thanks!